# Symlink for a README.md file from another Repository

Tags: github, symlink

I'm wondering wheather this is possible with GitHub.

As you can see below, I have two respositories. One is Primary, where I'm writing some of the Common MarkDown files for some of my Projects. Two, is the actual Project Repo, where I want to refer the Markdown file fomr Repo1 as a symlink and render it.

```
RepoOne - 

/abhinavbharadwajr
../absolutebeginner.md

RepoTwo -

/pythonexamples
../Absolute Beginner
../../absolutebeginner.md
```

Is this Possible? I have seen people creating symlink within a Single Repository, but not like this.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible.  First of all, GitHub doesn't check out files from separate repositories on disks.  All the repositories are bare, so there's no way to resolve the symlinks outside of the repository.  GitHub has no way to know that a repository symlink that points outside of the repository necessarily symlinks to another repository and what that is, since it could point to any possible location.

Comment: So, it there any Thir Party or OpenSoruce Code like a Renderer for MarkDown files to achieve this?

Comment: GitHub doesn't let you use third-party renderers on their site because they don't allow JavaScript for security reasons.  You can of course build the README on your local system or in a CI environment and upload the results somewhere if you like.